# Finding power series of $\,f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=1/(1+z^2)$ and we want to find the power series in $a=1$. I think we have to write $1/(1+z^2)=1/(1+(z-1)+1)^2=1/(1+(1+(z-1)^2+2(z-1)))$, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: To find the power series you have to compute derivatives, right? Like in the Taylor expansion. Simply do that!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{1+z}=\frac1{2+(z-1)}=\frac12\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}2}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{z-1}2\right)^k$$

The above is true for

$$\left|\frac{z-1}2\right|<1\iff |z-1|<2$$

Well, now just substitute $\;z\to w^2\;$ :

$$\frac1{1+w^2}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{w^2-1}2\right)^k$$

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't a power series in $w$.

Comment: You are right, @AntonioVargas. I'm not sure though whether this is enough for the OP or not. Perhaps I'll add something later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first write $\zeta = z-1$, so that

$$
\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{2 + 2\zeta + \zeta^2},
$$

so that now we're looking for a power series about the point $\zeta = 0$, i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{2 + 2\zeta + \zeta^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \zeta^n.
$$

By clearing the denominator of the left-hand side we get

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= \left(2 + 2\zeta + \zeta^2\right) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \zeta^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2a_n \zeta^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2a_n \zeta^{n+1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \zeta^{n+2} \\
&= 2a_0 + 2a_1\zeta + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2a_n \zeta^n + 2a_0 \zeta + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2a_n \zeta^{n+1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \zeta^{n+2} \\
&= 2a_0 + 2a_1\zeta + \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} 2a_m \zeta^m + 2a_0 \zeta + \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} 2a_{m-1} \zeta^m + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{m-2} \zeta^m \\
&= 2a_0 + 2(a_0+a_1)\zeta + \sum_{m=2}^\infty (2a_m + 2a_{m-1} + a_{m-2})\zeta^m.
\end{align}
$$

Sending $\zeta \to 0$ we get $2a_0 = 1$ or $a_0 = 1/2$.  After substituting this into the above equation and cancelling we get

$$
0 = 2(a_0+a_1)\zeta + \sum_{m=2}^\infty (2a_m + 2a_{m-1} + a_{m-2})\zeta^m.
$$

Dividing by $\zeta$ then sending $\zeta \to 0$ yields $a_0 + a_1 = 0$ or $a_1 = -1/2$.  Substituting this back in then repeating the process we find that

$$
2a_m + 2a_{m-1} + a_{m-2} = 0
$$

for all $m \geq 2$.

In other words, the coefficients of the power series for $\left(2 + 2\zeta + \zeta^2\right)^{-1}$ satisfy the recurrence relation

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&a_0 = 1/2, \\
&a_1 = -1/2, \\
&2a_m + 2a_{m-1} + a_{m-2} = 0 \quad \text{for } m \geq 2.
\end{align}
\right.
$$

This is a linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients, so we can find the solution by guessing the form $a_m = \lambda^m$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.  This yields

$$
2\lambda^m + 2\lambda^{m-1} + \lambda^{m-2} = 0
$$

or, upon dividing through by $\lambda^{m-2}$,

$$
2\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 1 = 0,
$$

so that $\lambda = (-1\pm i)^{-1}$.  Thus the general solution to the recurrence relation is given by

$$
a_m = \frac{A}{(-1+i)^m} + \frac{B}{(-1-i)^m},
$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.  We can determine these constants by applying the initial conditions $a_0 = 1/2$ and $a_1 = -1/2$.  Setting $m=0$ yields

$$
\frac{1}{2} = A + B,
$$

and setting $m=1$ yields

$$
-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{A}{-1+i} + \frac{B}{-1-i}.
$$

From the first equation we get $B = 1/2-A$, so that the second becomes

$$
-\frac{1}{2} = A \left(\frac{1}{-1+i} - \frac{1}{-1-i}\right) + \frac{1}{2(-1-i)} = -iA + \frac{1}{2(-1-i)},
$$

so that $A = \frac{1}{2(1+i)}$ and thus $B = \frac{1}{2(1-i)}$.  Therefore the coefficients of the power series are given by

$$
a_m = \frac{1}{2(1+i)(-1+i)^m} + \frac{1}{2(1-i)(-1-i)^m}.
$$

After substituting $\zeta = z-1$ we conclude that

$$
\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m (z-1)^m.
$$

If you'd like, you can use De Moivre's formula to rewrite the coefficients as

$$
a_m = - 2^{-(m+1)/2} \cos\left(\frac{3}{4}(m-1)\pi\right),
$$

so that

> $$
> \frac{1}{1+z^2} = -\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} 2^{-(m+1)/2} \cos\left(\frac{3(m-1)}{4}\pi\right) (z-1)^m.
> $$

This method is general and will work for any rational function $P(z)/Q(z)$ -- the coefficients of rational function always satisfy a recurrence relation of this type, and in fact this characterizes rational functions.  The coefficients of the power series can then be written as linear combinations of powers of the roots of the characteristic equation.  Of course you may not always be able to write down the roots explicitly if the equation is of degree $> 4$.

Comment: Let me know if you need help with any of these steps and I will be glad to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hm, it's not the way we learnt to do. I think I have to do it in DonAntonio's way, because a ansatz solution we didn't learn.

Comment: You may have learned it under a different name -- are you sure you haven't learned how to solve recurrence relations of the form $Pa_n + Qa_{n-1} + R a_{n-2} = 0$?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the details of the calculation, if you're interested.